# Cannot read property 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using javascript with ruby on rails but when I try to pass the addEventListener is say null

I am passing the javascript through a call

html:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h1 class="logo">Doujins Latinos</h1>
    <span class="icon-menu btb-menu" id="btb-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
    <nav class="nav" id="nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link select" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link"href="">Curso</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link"href="">Docente</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link"href="">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<script>
  new toogleView();
</script>
```

js:

```
function toogleView(){
  var btnMenu = document.getElementById('btn-menu');
  var nav = document.getElementById('nav');

  btnMenu.addEventListener('click', function(){
    nav.classList.toggle('mostrar');
  });
}
```

I will really appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: typo in your id in your html `btb-menu`. Therefore `btnMenu` is `undefined`.

Comment: You can just call the function with `toogleView()` rather than `new toogleView()`.

Comment: Thanks my mistake